# Indentation in HTML without unwanted whitespaces

Tags: html, css, indentation

When using indentation in my HTML code, it creates a whitespace between elements in different lines.

```html
<div id="nbcntcnt">
  <a href="notset.html" class="nbcntbutton" id="snbb">Übersicht</a>
  <a href="notset.html" class="nbcntbutton">Technische Daten</a>
  <a href="notset.html" class="nbcntbutton">Vergleichen</a>
  <a href="notset.html" class="nbcntbutton">Zum Pixel wechseln</a>
</div>
```

Result of given Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZkfi.jpg

As you can see, there is a whitespace between each link. I found out if I remove the indentation it'll remove the whitespaces. Is there a way to get rid of the whitespaces without making my code ugly?

edit: The problem is not caused by the css. After completely removing css from my website, the problem was still there (as also to be seen if you run the code snippet).

Comment: Can you post your CSS too?

Comment: Seems like css is causing the problem. Please include css for class="nbcntbutton" in your question.

Comment: please include all the code here, or where you can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#nbcntcnt{
    display: inline-flex;
    /* OR
    display:flex;   
    */
}
```

Use any one of the display to you id and your indentation will be gone. Good Luck!